# How to set the document to move up and down while sliding the mouse wheel, while the mouse position does not change?

Tags: vimrc

When I use the mouse wheel to slide the document, the document does not move at first, but the mouse cursor moves. How can I set the mouse cursor not to move while the document moves, so I don’t have to always find where my mouse cursor is.

The following instructions are what I found, but they have no effect.

```
nnoremap <A-j> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <A-k> :m .-2<CR>==
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
vnoremap <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

My Linux server version is：`Linux version 4.15.0-122-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-010) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #124~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP`.

I am using a terminal to connect to the server. The terminal used is **MobaXterm**

Comment: Which operating system are you on? The behavior of the scroll wheel can depend on the O.S... Are you running a GUI version of Vim (such as GVim or MacVim) or are you running it on a terminal? If on a terminal, which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added information

Comment: The commands you pasted are mappings for moving the current line or visual selection up and down within the document (i.e. editing the text), so they’re definitely not what you’re looking for.

Comment: Do you know what I should do? Thank you.

Comment: do you have any `mouse` config in your vimrc?  like `set mouse=a`?

Answer (score 1):

Like Rich mentioned, the vim config you posted is unrelated to the mouse.

You might try adding:

```
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif
```

...to your `.vimrc`.

In regards to:

> so I don’t have to always find where my mouse cursor is

`set cursorline` is a handy option for making the position of the cursor easily detectable.